# How to Add Checkboxes And Search to Dynamic Grid..?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My View

```
 <div class="modal-body clearfix no-padding no-scroll">
        <div data-kendo-grid=""
             data-k-data-source="vm.listDataSource"
             data-k-sortable="true"
             data-k-pageable="true"
             data-k-selectable="vm.isSelectable"
             data-k-on-change="vm.onSelect(kendoEvent)"></div>
    </div>
```

My DataSource

```
 this.performanceReportService.getSQLdetails(this.$scope.item.ReportConfigDetailID).then((data: any) => {
            this.listOfItems = angular.copy(data);
            this.listDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: this.listOfItems,
                pageSize: 10,
                sort: [],
            });
        }, () => {
            });
```

how will i put checkbox in each of this row..? this is dynamic grid..? rows nd Colomuns generates Dynamically..

Comment: Need a Serach box Urgently on this Grid..Can any1 help..?